# How to get rid of the class/method is never used android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am running a code were it detects the highest sound made in the room. I have written my code (with some help), but warnings keep popping up saying that the class and methods aren't used. Please help.

```
public class SoundMeter {

    private MediaRecorder soundCapture = null;

    public void start() throws IOException {
        if (soundCapture == null) {
            soundCapture = new MediaRecorder();
            soundCapture.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            soundCapture.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            soundCapture.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            soundCapture.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
            soundCapture.prepare();
            soundCapture.start();

        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (soundCapture != null) {
            soundCapture.stop();
            soundCapture.release();
            soundCapture = null;
        }
    }

    public double getAmplitude() {
        if (soundCapture != null){
            return soundCapture.getMaxAmplitude();
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually using it?  If you aren't, then that's why they appear.  Also, its not necessarily wrong to have a few of those-  if its functionality you used to use and may again, or functionality you just aren't using yet but will soon.  The problem is when you get many of those and code may become out of date.

Answer (score 1):

If there are methods that aren't used, and you have no plan to use them, you should just delete them. They take up space in the APK and space is valuable when you only have 100MB before you have to use expansion files.

Some tools like Proguard can optimize away unused methods, but again, if there's no use for it, get rid of it.

If there are unused methods and classes you are planning to use, do not delete them.

Android Studio shows suggestions if you click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, including removal, which you can apply to the entire file if you don't want to remove them manually.

And if you plan on using them, you can get rid of the warning by suppressing it - again <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but click the arrow left, and it'll auto-generate a suppression annotation for whatever scope you want, or my manually adding:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

To the scope you want to suppress it in (as in either the class, or only the function).

But remember: it's a warning, **not** an error. You can ignore it, as it doesn't have any consequences aside a potentially bloated APK/Jar

Comment: Sorry. What I was trying to say is how can I run the class. I don't want to get rid of it. Can anyone help me because I don't know how to run it and the message "this class isn't used", or "this method isn't used" is popping up

Comment: call the method. If it is called methodOne(); somewhere you have to do someclass.methodOne(); but it is only a suggested warning. You do not have to do anything

Comment: where would I call it